# fb (#200) Permissions error even though I have "public_actions" permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to do a fb like from my android app.

I have logged in with FB and got active session and auth token.

I'm trying to do a "like" to a photo on my wall.

The url is: 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10154208667515153&set=a.1015467405153.10741857.685560152&type=1&theater

so I assume the postId is `10154208667515153` ?

I then try this code with the ui thread.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                        if (session == null) {

                        }
                        List<String> re = session.getPermissions();

                        Request request = new Request(session,
                                "486130591514106" + "/likes", null,
                                HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                        // Request complete

                                        String re = response.toString();
                                    }
                                });
                        request.executeAsync();
```

with the permissions:

```
[publish_checkins, status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, email, create_note, share_item, publish_stream, publish_actions, user_birthday, user_location, user_likes, user_interests, user_friends, user_status, basic_info]
```

but i get the following error:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}, isFromCache:false}
```

Comment: Why do you assume that's the post ID? why are you working from the photo URL in that example? you should be getting the actual ID when you make the API call that returns you the photo in the response

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks. btw, how about the official example? is this a template url or does it need to be replace completely? `("object", "http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791");`

Comment: That's a URL to a sample open graph object which exists off-Facebook - I don't think it's directly related - to get a post ID you'd typically call the search API (deprecated in v2.0), `<user>/feed`, `<page>/feed`, etc 
It should be possible to like photos with the appropriate permissions from a user who can themselves like the photo, but trying to construct an ID manually is risky as they're intended to be opaque

Comment: meaning this sample url should work first for my like. then I can move on to facebook photos?